# unable to access sql server remotely (error says :the remote system refused the network connection)

Tags: c#, sql-server

I tried using windows authentication but the server I'm using is also an active directory server so I'm using sql authentication instead.

```
public const string con = "Data source=192.168.56.101,1433" + ";" +"Database=" +
    database + ";" + "User ID=" + user + ";" + "password=" + password;
```

this is the connection string

Also I carefully configured and reconfigured Sqlserver to allow remote connections and completely turned the firewall off

Comment: Can you connect using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: yes , i can also ping the remote server harboring the database from my device

Comment: Rather than specifying the database with "Database=", have you tried "Initial Catalog=" ?

Read more at https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connect-via-an-ip-address/

Comment: yes i tried but will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, as i suspected the port 1433 was not the the default port for TCP connection due to the server being on virtual machine,
The solution was to reset the config for SQL server management TCP protocol to using dynamic ports and listen to all,

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that TCP/IP is enabled in SQL Server. You can find that setting in the Sql Server Configuration Manager, under the Sql Server Network Configuration.
Once it's enabled, under the properties of the TCP/IP configuration, in the IP Addresses tab, make sure your IP is active and note the port (1433 is the default).

Open the TCP port (1433 is the default) in the firewall.
Also make sure that your connection string follows a connection string that is understood by the provider. For SQL Server one can be:

Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

refer to [connectionstrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for more details

Comment: i reconfigured the server to make the ip address a static one and specified the TCP port to 1433 and deactivated the automatic TCP port allocation, also I added "Network Library=DBMSSOCN"  to override named pipes, now at least i know it's not the connection string